# How safe is Twitter4j and future support for the Twitter API

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

I just started with Twitter APP Development for Android and since there is no official SDK for Android[took me quite some time to wrap my head around it as I had just moved from FB], many have suggested using Twitter4j.
***What I want to know***

**1. Is it safe in using this framework or should I stick with the
    official REST API calls given by Twitter[personal choice].

 2.  Since it does not cover all the API calls can we mix and match the REST
    service calls like if I authenticate my app/user through Twitter4j
    is it possible to have other API calls**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using the jar myself for oAuth implementation i must say it's quite good. 
EVEN TWITTER SUPPORTS THE USAGE OF THIS
here's the link,                                                      https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/twitter-libraries to support my claim.
About the library: it's pretty good and easy to use.
But i just used it for oAuth and tested some of the methods. I works...
Here's a tutorial link of the usage
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/
for the api calls not covered in the twitter4j you can do it on your own

Answer (score 0):

1. I would say yes. It has always been under active development and if you check out the github repo, the last commit was only 5 days ago.
2. Yes.

Comment: hey @shivam thanks for the reply but they do not have any active FAQ section that support the same theory, I mean the active commit for the repository is a nice observation. would like to know if you have used this feature in the past and satisfied with the performance

Comment: Well, you can't have any official statement since it's an unofficial library. But it has 80 contributors, and has been around for long. But well you can never be too sure.

Comment: One of the best measures to check if a lib is going to be around for long is if its currently under active development and twitter4j sure is.